# R: Is 'spatialSign' function useful for identifying outliers?

Tags: r, outliers

Here's my question:

What is the purpose of the "spatialSign" function in the 'AppliedPredictiveModeling' package?
I have read in a book about a "spatial sign" method that identifies outliers. The function projects the values of a variable in circle and if there are outliers, they're supposed to appear inside the circle. Is that the same "spatial sign" R uses in this package?

If so, how come when I submit this code:

```
plotSubset <- data.frame(scale(zquant1[, c("AGE", "FL")]))
xyplot(AGE ~ FL,
       data = plotSubset,
       auto.key = list(columns = 10))
transformed <- spatialSign(plotSubset)
transformed <- as.data.frame(transformed)
xyplot(AGE ~ FL,
       data = transformed,
       auto.key = list(columns = 2))
```

it may look like I have an outlier in the first image, but the spatial sign method (2nd image) doesn't identify it?

[(1st image) http://www.imagesup.net/?di=5142245473711](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=5142245473711)
[(2nd image) http://www.imagesup.net/?di=5142245489110](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=5142245489110)

Comment: Thank you 'rcs' for the edit, I don't have the level that permits inserting photos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it cannot identify outliers. It is just a preprocessing method, which brings the outliers towards the majority of the data.

Excerpt from the [Applied Predictive Modeling book](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/):

> If a model is considered to be sensitive to outliers, one data
>   transformation that can minimize the problem is the spatial sign
>   (Serneels et al. 2006). This procedure projects the predictor values
>   onto a multidimensional sphere. This has the effect of making all the
>   samples the same distance from the center of the sphere.

Serneels, Sven, Evert De Nolf, and Pierre J. Van Espen. 2006. “Spatial Sign Preprocessing: A Simple Way to Impart Moderate Robustness to Multivariate Estimators.” Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling 46 (3): 1402–9. doi:10.1021/ci050498u.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
tmp <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(n, 0, 0.02), -1, 1, 0.5),
                  y=c(rnorm(n, 0, 0.2), -1, 1, -2))

plot(tmp, asp=1, col=c(rep(1,n), 2, 3, 4), pch=19)
grid()
plot(spatialSign(tmp), asp=1, col=c(rep(1,n), 2, 3, 4), pch=19)
grid()
```

[image: spatialSign example]

Comment: Is there any reason the why the spatialSign function is no longer included in the package?

Comment: You can find this function in the caret package.